# Python Response Decoding

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, urllib, html-encode

For the following lines that use `urllib`:

```
# some request object exists
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read().decode("utf8")
```

What format of string does `read()` return? I've been trying t figure that out form Python's documentation but it does not mention it at all. Why is there a `decode`? Does `decode` decode an object **to** utf-8 or **from** utf-8? From what format to what format does it decode it to? `decode` documentation also mentions nothing about that. Is it that Python's documentation is that terrible, or is it that I don't understand some standard convention?

I want to store that HTML in a UTF-8 file. Would I just do a regular write, or do I need to "encode" back into something and write that?

*Note: I know urllib is deprecated, but I cannot switch to urllib2 right now*

Comment: Thanks for down votes without a comment...?

Comment: [How do I stop the pain?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask python:

```
>>> r=urllib.urlopen("http://google.com")
>>> a=r.read()
>>> type(a)
0: <type 'str'>
>>> help(a.decode)
Help on built-in function decode:

decode(...)
    S.decode([encoding[,errors]]) -> object

    Decodes S using the codec registered for encoding. encoding defaults
    to the default encoding. errors may be given to set a different error
    handling scheme. Default is 'strict' meaning that encoding errors raise
    a UnicodeDecodeError. Other possible values are 'ignore' and 'replace'
    as well as any other name registered with codecs.register_error that is
    able to handle UnicodeDecodeErrors.

>>> b = a.decode('utf8')
>>> type(b)
1: <type 'unicode'>
>>>
```

So, it appears that `read()` returns an `str`. `.decode()` decodes *from* UTF-8 to Python's internal unicode format.

Comment: For some reason, the `decode()` doc page I was on was a different one. Thanks

Comment: So a `str` does not support all unicode characters, thus `decode()` chained after `read()`?